# How to create a column using initials of other column

Tags: ios, sql, sqlite, core-data

I am making an app in IOS which makes use of database stored in **.sqlite** file. So i'm using **core data** to access my database.
Here i have a column in the table having names of persons,
What i want is **to create a new column using this column's values** like a hint(say only initials)

e.g.  JOHNNY DEPP -> J##### D###

after googling for hours, i'm still in search of solution to this
Please suggest how to do it ..
either way(**core data** or **.sqlite commands**)

any help is appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean that you want 1 new column to store each person's initials?

Comment: yes sir, exactly .. not just initials… in some form of hint like i showed in example

Comment: I'm not sure what you googled, but it took me less than a minute to find the answer with a search string of, "sqlite alter table add column".

Comment: sir, i'm not that familiar with .sqlite commands and i've seen that link you posted..but i cannot create desired results from it as i want it to be like a hint(showing initials and no of letters),. thanx for considering

Comment: One step at a time.  You can't populate a column until you add it to the table.

Comment: OK,, after adding the column with some default value,, how'd i set those (hint) values to that column

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40120/discussion-between-nickatstack-and-dan-bracuk)